# Text Moves When browser resizes

Tags: css, browser, text, resize

Im working on a site right now, and I have run into the problem with my text. When I zoom out, the text begins to stack and actually goes out of my div. I have the div at a fixed width and height, and have it wrapped out in other divs, and cant figure this out for the life of me. Only the text moves though, everything else stays put. It looks kinda likes this

Desired:

> this is my text
>   in the way that
>   I want it to be

actual:

> this
>   is
>   the
>   text

As I zoom out the text tends to stack up and push out of the div.

```
   .content {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .contentleft{
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
   }

    .contentright{
    float: right;
    width: 480px;
    }

    .boxone {
    float: left;
    clear:both;
    height: 211px;
    width: 230px;
    background-image:url(../images/rec1.png);
    }

    .textone {
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear: both;

   }
```

HTML

```
     <div class=content>
            <div class=contentleft>
                <div class=boxone>

                    <div class=textone>
                 <p> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </p> 

                    </div>
                    <div class=learnone>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=boxtwo>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class=contentright>
                <div class=boxthree>
                </div>
                <div class=boxfour>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

what can I do to stop that text from moving?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KkUAV/ heres the code in question, although it doesnt show off my zoom out problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser behaviour to zoom all the items in the page, but as a developer you can specify a font-size in pixel.

```
font-size:12px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple just increasing the width of the div.
Example

```
.contentleft {
    width: 800px;
}
```